# How to force LaTeX to put even pages on the right hand side in documentclass article

Tags: margins, page-numbering, double-sided

In documentclass article I try to put even pages on the right hand side of a twoside document (unfortunatelly it is no option for me to change the document class).

My point is to start with pagenumber 1 on the right hand side with correct margins (from pages on the right side). Any ideas how to achieve that ?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
... content on the left
\newpage
... content on the right
\cleardoublepage
... content on the left
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
... content should be on the right but is placed on the left side caused by change
    in pagenumbering which leads to pagenumber reset to 1 (which is intended)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you think you don't start at the right hand side? Add the package `showframe` and you will see the correct result.

Comment: Well, thanks for asking the RIGHT question: In my opinion right pages have margins on the left side. As I found out, the other way round is "correct"! Therefore, with changing the idea a solution can be found ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `article` class and the `twoside` class option enabled, the outer page margins will be twice as large as the inner margins (conforming to rather venerable typographic rules ;-)), and there is no binding correction. It seems you assumed LaTeX would horizontally center the textblock and add some binding correction, and so you took even (left-hand) pages for odd (right-hand) pages and vice versa.

As you cannot use another class, try the `geometry` package and its `hcentering` and `bindingoffset` options -- this should result in the desired margins.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[hcentering,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This changes the `\textwidth` how can this be avoided?

Comment: @71GA `geometry` allows to tweak the textwidth using the `textwidth` key-value option. See section 5.3 of the documentation for details.

Answer (score 6):

In twosided (recto-verso) documents, near-universal typographic practice is to have the right-hand or recto pages be odd-numbered and hence the the left-hand or verso pages be even-numbered. This practice is carried out by LaTeX if the `twoside` option is in force (or if you choose a documentclass, such as `book`, where twoside is the default).

If you really want to deviate from this practice (at least that's what I understand you want to do), just issue the following commands right after the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` instruction:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{a} % enter some "invisible text"
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1} % reset the page counter variable
```

It's admittedly kludgy, but it works.

Comment: OK, since in my opinion, a page on the left hand side has some extra margin on the right (just for binding) and the other way round I thought that latex just started an article (twoside) on the left hand side.

Comment: In two-sided printing, it is customary (but it's not a law!) to have the outer margins be slightly wider than the inner margins (those closer to the spine/binding). However, that's a separate issue from that of the page-numbering style. There's nothing to stop you from having the text of your document start on the left-hand side of a two-sided document. Nevertheless, I wouldn't go against the practice of having left-hand side pages be even-numbered. Of course, if you stick with this approach, your document would start on page "2".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to answer my own question but this is not allowed at this time (in 6 hrs). I'm still confused about the way margins are normally added to even/odd pages but with this knowledge it's quite simple to get what you want (eg. bindingoffset from geometry package). 
Nevertheless, thanks to all who answered. Maybe, if someone else is having the same "wrong" opinion, he/she could avoid wasting time by reading that postings and change his/her mind.

Comment: @roland: I'm quite sure that similar questions will turn up in the future. (BTW, welcome at tex.sx!)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coercing `article.cls` into doing something it never really was intended to do, it's probably easier to use another class instead. A relatively simple solution is to use `memoir.cls`:

```
\documentclass[article,twoside]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The largest document divider}
Memoir uses \verb+\chapter+ for articles as well as books, and
it's smart enough to not display \verb+\chaptername+ when
the \verb+article+ option is given.
\section{The second largest one}
Note that \verb+\section+ gets numbered as X.Y instead.
\end{document}
```