# Two questions about Classic Thesis

Tags: biblatex, classicthesis, author-number

The first is that, although I like the fact that long citations are in the form J. Doe et al. in the chapters, I don't want it in the actual bibliography ; how can I do that?

The second is that the pages seems "inverted" ; when I print my thesis, pages that should be on the right are even-numbered for some reason.. and therefore the alignment and the margins are not on the correct side, how can I change it?

Comment: Since your two questions are entirely unrelated, it's best to ask them as two separate questions. This way, other users can find just the question (and hopefully soon the solution as well) that they need, people who can only answer one question don't have to hesitate posting, and credit (= upvotes) will be given for each solution to each problem. I recommend editing this post to get rid of one question and posting that as another question.

Comment: The first question has nothing to do with ClassicThesis, but rather with the bibliography manager (**natbib** or **biblatex**). The second questions has an easy answer: the format has very wide outer margins. The odd numbered pages *are* the left pages.

Comment: With regard to your first question: Try to add the biblatex package option `maxbibnames=99`. For details see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography

Comment: With regard to your second question: If you really want smaller outer margins, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/how-to-force-latex-to-put-even-pages-on-the-right-hand-side-in-documentclass-arti